# GNU sed long substitutions

Tags: sed

I have long sed substitution expressions in a bash script.

I don't particularly like having such long lines, is it possible to have them split on several lines, i.e.

```
sed -r -e 's/
    match/
    replacement/
    options'
```

This would avoid ending up with lines that have 100+ characters, but i've never seen this before using sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Perl` will let you do this - I recommend [looking that up](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/cookbook/ch06_05.htm) if it's an option -
but in `sed` you can still use a quoted line break, if perhaps not with the indentation.

```
sed -r -e 's/'\
'match/'\
'replacement/'\
'options'
```

In use:

```
$: echo this needs some match | sed -r -e 's/'\
> 'match/'\
> 'replacement/'\
> 'g'
this needs some replacement
```

Comment: Your solution indeed works without any indentation which is still better than long lines. I'd like to use your perl solution but this script is meant to run on a target that has no perl interpreter so...

Comment: We do what we must to get the job done. ;)